# Write own compiler on JVM with ASM Library, How ? First Steps?

Tags: java, jvm

I want create own jvm language as university project !

after investigation I found ASM library [HERE](http://asm.ow2.org/)

seems some languages in world use that for create own jvm language
but my question is

What is first steps for this purpose ?

for example I want create syntax like this :

```
public class A : B,IC,ID // Inheritance,Interfaces 
{
    public A(z:Integer) = // Constructor
       {

       }

    public Method(x:Integer,y:String):Float = // Method
       {

       }
}
```

How do I get started? 
focus on own Syntax or focus on language features

Is ASM Library useful for that ?

if yes , How can i found good tutorial for it ?
ASM 4 User Guide is so complicated

Is there any step by step tutorial for beginning ?

please guide me for first steps 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually compiler consists of 3 stages:

- parse source code and collect all information in internal representation (usually a tree)
- analyze internal representation to compute lacking information and/or optimize the code
- transform internal representation into target machine code (e.g. java bytecode)

ASM library can help to build only the 3d stage.

You should start from the first stage. First, try to write `Recursive Descent Parser` as in http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/. More complex example is [Dart Analyzer](https://github.com/SjB/Dart/tree/master/compiler/java/com/google/dart/compiler) - parses source code in dart language and creates internal representation, but does not generates bytecode.

Look at compiler-compilers like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to decide if for a novice, hand-made parser is easier to write than mastering such a complex tool.

Then look at the [List of JVMlanguages](http://www.quickiwiki.com/en/List_of_JVM_languages), find one that has syntax close to your language and is open-sourced, and change its parser at your desire.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a language designer, but this is how I did it in the past (in C# using C# Expressions).

1. Come up with your language first (syntax and semantics eg: * means multiply, it multiplies right operand with left ).IMHO This is the hardest part for an average computer programmer
2. Once your language is ready and complete, use parser generators like ANTLR to generate a language parser. with `ANTLR` you can generate parser in many languages including Java. ANTLR parser will parse your language (e.g: `2*3`) and raise events for you to handle. For example  call a method when it finds an operand (ANTLR would raise events in the order :`*23`).
3. In the ANTLR event handler, you can generate Java language constructs to deal with each event( for example: for '*' create a `MethodHandle` for multiply method, then capture next operands, pass those operands to `MethodHandel.invokeExact` , then print the result).ASM can be used to write the generated Method Handle to class file (using `CallSite`).

So there are three parts

1. Language design
2. Language syntax parsing
3. Generating jvm instructions.